# Pandas Extract Number with decimals from String

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract all numbers including decimals, dots and commas form a string using pandas.

This is my DataFrame

```
       rate_number    
0      92 rate
0      33 rate
0      9.25 rate
0    (4,396 total
0    (2,620 total
```

I tried using `df['rate_number'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)` but the results were not correct.

The DataFrame I need to extract should be the following:

```
    rate_number    
0      92 
0      33 
0      9.25 
0    4,396 
0    2,620
```

Comment: *"but the results were not correct."* - can you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe try `'(\d+[,.]?\d*)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['rate_number'] = df['rate_number'].replace('\(|[a-zA-Z]+', '', regex=True)
```

Better answer:

```
df['rate_number_2'] = df['rate_number'].str.extract('([0-9][,.]*[0-9]*)')
```

**Output:**

```
  rate_number rate_number_2
0         92             92
1         33             33
2       9.25           9.25
3      4,396          4,396
4      2,620          2,620
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error with the asterisk's position:

```
df['rate_number_2'] = df['rate_number'].str.extract('([0-9]*[,.][0-9]*)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan's comment above is not very noticeable but worked for me:

```
for df in df_arr:
    df = df.astype(str)
    df_copy = df.copy()
    for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
        df_copy[df.columns[i]]=df_copy[df.columns[i]].str.extract('(\d+[.]?\d*)', expand=False) #replace(r'[^0-9]+','')
    new_df_arr.append(df_copy)
```